# Versioning GitHub CODEOWNERS file

Tags: github

We have a git repo hosted on GitHub using "[a successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)".

To protect the master and dev branches, we have a pair of [CODEOWNERS files](https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/). PRs to master require the approval of user A, and PRs to dev require the approval of user A, B or C.

I'm not sure how to handle versioning of the CODEOWNERS files themselves. Ideally, we'd like them to remain static, however, initiating a PR between dev or master results in merge conflicts because of the differing CODEOWNERS files.

Is it possible for me to set up the branch history such that master/dev will not attempt to sync the CODEOWNERS files? What commits do I need to make?

I'm the repo admin, so can temporarily disable the PR requirements on master/dev.

Comment: If I understand the question (not sure I do), I don't think it's possible.

Comment: That was my feeling too. What I really want is static access controls for my master and dev branches.

Comment: An optional solution could be avoiding direct PRs from `dev` to `master`. It could work this way: branch from `dev` -> `tmp`. Fix the CODEOWNERS in `tmp` in order to make it identical to master's. Then create a PR from `tmp` to `master`. I suppose it should go without a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge a commit on a branch, without using its content.

In essence, you mark the commit as merged, so it won't come up again, but you discard the changes introduced.

To do that, on your master branch do:

```
git merge <git_commit_where_codeowners_is_modified> -s ours
```

Be careful, all the commits leading to the one you merged will also be considered merged, make sure those have been handled.

Comment: Wow 6 years old and no upvote on this excellent answer. Seems obvious now that you point it out.